# how to work on Index value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkcore

This is the Data in text file format. I need to find top salary for every city

```
first_name  last_name city          county       salary
--------------------------------------------------------
James        Butt     New Orleans   Orleans      250000
Josephine   Darakjy   Brighton      Livingston   300000
Art         Venere    Bridgeport    Gloucester   400000
Leota      Dilliard    Bridgeport   Gloucester   430000

> val scq = sc.textFile("path.txt")

> scq.flatMap(al=>al.split("\n")).sortBy(_._5,ascending = false).collect.take(5).foreach(println)
// sorting on salary
```

But I am getting error as `value _5 is not a member of String` , when I use `toString` it is giving error `value _5 is not a member of char`. 
How should it be handled?

Comment: `split` returns `Array` whose 5th  element will be accessed using `arr(4)`. `tup._5` is used to access the 5th element of a tuple. Also you might need to split the file with something apart from `\n` because `textFile` already  does that for you.

Comment: The entire line is considered a single column of string type. After splitting by line, you have to separate the columns using a delimiter. Then only you can use `_5`

Comment: @philantrovert  I did but yet got error **value _5 is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]**

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman **val againmap=flatma.map(_.split("\t"))** I am using it but still not working.

Comment: @RaviAnand did you even read philantrovert's comment properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
> val scq = sc.textFile("path.txt")
> val d = scq.map(_.split("\t")).sortBy(_.apply(4), ascending = false)
```

This will produce an `RDD[Array[String]]` as the output. If you want to view them as tuple, you can do the following:

```
> val d1 = d.map(c => (c(0), c(1), c(2), c(3), c(4))) // Prefer case class over this always
> d.collect.foreach(println)
```

This will produce the following output:

```
(Leota,Dilliard,Bridgeport,Gloucester,430000)
(Art,Venere,Bridgeport,Gloucester,400000)
(Josephine,Darakjy,Brighton,Livingston,300000)
(James,Butt,New Orleans,Orleans,250000)
```

Comment: I did this but I was getting                                                                              **[Ljava.lang.String;@3bd1d3ae
[Ljava.lang.String;@27b88459
[Ljava.lang.String;@4900e064
[Ljava.lang.String;@794c64e6**

Comment: Like I said that was `RDD[]Array[String]`. If you do `d.map(c => (c(0), c(1), c(2), c(3), c(4)))` you will be getting RDD tuple